angular app config file in the root build folder
I need to implement an app config folder that will be loaded when the app is initialized (APP_INITIALIZER) (example is in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-editable-config-files/). the issue is when you have localization enabled you have several folders (en, az, ru) when the app is built and in every folder, you have a configs folder. you need to change configs in every folder and it is very hard to keep them in sync. Do you have a solution for this issue?
dist/faq
 --en
   --configs
   --assets
 --ru
   --configs
   --assets
 --az
   --configs
   --assets

i need this structure
dist/faq
 --configs
 --en
   --assets
 --ru
   --assets
 --az
   --assets

angular.json
{
 "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
 "version": 1,
 "newProjectRoot": "projects",
 "projects": {
   "faq": {
     "root": "",
     "sourceRoot": "src",
     "projectType": "application",
     "prefix": "app",
     "schematics": {},
     "architect": {
       "build": {
         "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
         "options": {
           "localize": true,
           "outputPath": "dist/faq",
           "index": "src/index.html",
           "main": "src/main.ts",
           "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
           "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
           "assets": [
             "src/favicon.ico",
             "src/assets",
             {
               "glob": "**/*",
               "input": "src/assets/js/service-worker/",
               "output": "/"
             },
             {
               "glob": "app-configuration.json",
               "input": "src/configs/",
               "output": "configs/"
             }
           ],
           "styles": [
             "src/styles.scss",
             "src/global-scss/table-style.scss",
             "src/global-scss/theme-1.scss",
             "src/global-scss/theme-2.scss",
             "src/global-scss/theme-3.scss",
             "src/global-scss/theme-4.scss"
           ],
           "scripts": [],
           "vendorChunk": true,
           "extractLicenses": false,
           "buildOptimizer": false,
           "sourceMap": true,
           "optimization": false,
           "namedChunks": true
         },
         "configurations": {
           "production": {
             "localize": ["ru", "az"],
             "budgets": [
               {
                 "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                 "maximumWarning": "6kb"
               }
             ],
             "fileReplacements": [
               {
                 "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                 "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
               }
             ],
             "optimization": true,
             "outputHashing": "all",
             "sourceMap": false,
             "namedChunks": false,
             "extractLicenses": true,
             "vendorChunk": false,
             "buildOptimizer": true
           },
           "ru": {
             "localize": ["ru"]
           },
           "az": {
             "localize": ["az"]
           }
         },
         "defaultConfiguration": ""
       },
       "serve": {
         "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
         "options": {
           "browserTarget": "faq:build"
         },
         "configurations": {
           "production": {
             "browserTarget": "faq:build:production"
           },
           "ru": {
             "browserTarget": "faq:build:ru"
           },
           "az": {
             "browserTarget": "faq:build:az"
           }
         }
       },
       "extract-i18n": {
         "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
         "options": {
           "browserTarget": "faq:build"
         }
       },
       "test": {
         "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
         "options": {
           "main": "src/test.ts",
           "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
           "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
           "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
           "styles": ["src/styles.scss", "src/themes.scss"],
           "scripts": [],
           "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"]
         }
       }
     },
     "i18n": {
       "sourceLocale": "en",
       "locales": {
         "ru": {
           "baseHref": "ru/",
           "translation": "src/locales/messages.ru.xlf"
         },
         "az": {
           "baseHref": "az/",
           "translation": "src/locales/messages.az.xlf"
         }
       }
     }
   },
   "faq-e2e": {
     "root": "e2e/",
     "projectType": "application",
     "architect": {
       "e2e": {
         "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
         "options": {
           "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
           "devServerTarget": "faq:serve"
         },
         "configurations": {
           "production": {
             "devServerTarget": "faq:serve:production"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 },
 "schematics": {
   "@schematics/angular:component": {
     "style": "scss"
   }
 },
 "cli": {
   "analytics": "5cb03c1f-c147-4fbb-977b-2a3f3c5936a8"
 }
}




when you run a build, all the config folder will have the same source code, what do you mean by "you need to change configs in every folder and it is very hard to keep them in sync"

if you don't need to build a source code again, but you need to change some configuration, in most cases it is done by dev ops team, they don't have access to source code, they have only built files
